# Django: how to exclude instances in other model's relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models:

```
Model A:
    field1

Model B:
    a_list = ManyToManyField(A)
```

Now, I want to find A not in the list of B's a_list, like:

```
A.objects.exclude(self__in=b.a_list)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines should work:

`A.objects.all().exclude(pk__in=b.a_list)`

Comment: `b.a_list` is the value for a specific `b`. The question isn't very clear, but I believe the OP wants to exclude all possible values of the `a_list` field.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key is a single instance so you can try following solution also

if b is a Model B single instance

```
A.objects.exclude(id=b.a_list.id)
```

If b is

```
b = B.objects.all()
A.objects.exclude(id__in=[i.a_list.id for i in b])
```